# When rotating, UIPopoverController displayed from UITableViewCell is incorrectly placed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover that displays from a UITableViewCell in a UITableView, which is the only view in a modal dialog. This works fine in both landscape and portrait:

```
UIViewController *content = [[SetTimeClockTimeViewController alloc] init];
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
[popover setDelegate:self];
UITableViewCell *cell = [dataTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[dataTable indexPathForSelectedRow]];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:cell.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

However, when the screen is rotated while the popover remains up, the popover shifts away from the cell (if I rotate back it shifts to the proper location). This happens if either orientation is the starting orientation. I tried implementing `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:`, but nothing I've put in it appears to have fixed the problem. For example:

```
- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view {
    // TODO: Popover moves wrong when rotating
    UITableViewCell *cell = [dataTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[dataTable indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    *rect = cell.frame;
    *view = cell.superview;
}
```

I've tried telling the table to `reloadData` when rotating, using `convertRect:toView` to have `self.view` as the view, and calling `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, but none of those seemed to fix the improper placement.

How can I ensure the popover is displayed from the new cell location after rotation?

Example of the popover displaying in portrait (arrow points to "Time" row):
[image: Example of the popover displaying in portrait]

After orientation to landscape (arrow should point to "Time" row):
[image: After orientation to landscape]

Comment: Did you tried to translate the cell frame to the main view frame ?

Comment: @danypata Do you mean `convertRect:toView:`? Or `CGAffineTransformTranslate`? I've tried the former, though I may have done it incorrectly. I haven't tried the latter - I'm not sure how (if?) it would apply.

Comment: First one is the right one. But you should do it in `willAnimateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: @danypata I changed it to `[cell.superview convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view]` in `willAnimate...` and that fixed it. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would do it. But I see that you already accepted another answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popovers displayed from a view do not maintain a relationship with the view, and might more often than not shift to incorrect places after rotation. This is unlike displaying from a bar button item, where the popover will move after layout. You should move the popover to the correct location in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the view controller.

Make sure to convert the returned rectangle to the view's correct coordinate system by using `convertRect:toView:` or `convertRect:fromView:`.

Comment: That's what I was attempting to do using [`popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:) - my understanding was by manually setting the `rect` to the new frame, I'd get the right position in the new orientation. Did I misunderstand what I was supposed to do there?

Comment: You should translate the rect into the superview coordinate system. Try `convertRect:toView:`.

Comment: By superview, do you mean the view holding the TableView? Or the TableView? Isn't the CGRect returned as the frame supposed to be relative to the superview, and wouldn't that be the TableView for a TableViewCell?

Comment: Hm, you are right. I must admit, I have no experience with `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:`, I move my popovers manually after rotation. This works. Perhaps due to the presented view controller is in a form sheet, it causes the layout system to confuse.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried switching to `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `convertRect:toView:` (like you and danypata suggested above), which works, but if I do the same thing in `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:` it does not. Must be something I'm missing there.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillLayout`, `viewDidLayout`, `willRotate`, `didRotate`, `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:`. See the order of calls.

Comment: When doing a straight rotation, looks like it called `willAnimateRotation...`, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, and then `popoverController:willReposition...`. Everything else seems to have only been called when first loading the modal dialog.

Comment: You must hear `willLayout` and `didLayout` during rotation. I fear that the system asks for the rect before layouting the form sheet view, thus you do not have the correct rect to pass.

Comment: Makes sense. Also, since I ended up solving this with  `convertRect:toView:` (like you mentioned in your comment), did you want to update your answer to also cover that so I can accept? Not saying the current one is wrong, just that it's not how I solved this :P

Answer (score 1):

You should translate the rect to the superview using `convertRect:toView`. The most important part is to call it in `willAnimateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have seen for this is to use the cell(or in my case a UIButton) as the sourceView and the cell's bounds as the sourceRect.
i.e.

```
[popover 
   presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds //vs cell.frame
   inView:cell                        //vs cell.superView
   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
   animated:YES];
```